# Altered column in Hive, showing Null value in Spark SQL result

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, hive, apache-spark-sql

I need to alter one column name in Hive, so I did that with below query. After altering I could see the result in hive for "select columnnm1 from tablename"

```
alter table tablename change columnnm1 columnnm2 string;
```

But when I tried to execute the select columnnm2 from spark.sql I am getting NULL values, whereas I could see valid values in hive.

It's managed table. I tried spark metadata refresh, still no luck. As of now I am dropping old table and creating new hive table with correct column name works. But how to handle this ALTER scenario.

```
spark.catalog.refreshTable("<tablename>")
```

Thank you.

Comment: Hi and welcome to SO. Could you please provide the exact command you are using in spark.sql? Also did you try: `spark.table`? Is the result the same?

Comment: hi @pythonic833 df=spark.sql("select columnm1 from tablename"). So before altering the hive table I could see the valid values for df.show(). After altering in hive table, i'm getting null when I executing df1=spark.sql("select columnm2 from tablename"). df1.show()

spark.table? can you please tell me how to execute with that command, I will try

Comment: `df=spark.table(<table_name>)`. Could you also please execute `df1.printSchema()` and post the result here.

Comment: same output. null

Comment: Could it be, that you actually converted all values in the table to null by changing the values to string?

Comment: Please provide the result of `df1.printSchema()` and the result of show the result of `show creat table <table_name>` from hive.

Comment: old data type is also String in hive. After altering column name i could see the valid values in Hue. Spark.sql correctly identifies the column name, when I gave old name, it throws error. df.printSchema() also gives correct datatype as String but value is still Null.

Comment: show Create table tablename
CREATE TABLE 'tablename'(
...
coulmnnm1 string,
...)
ROW FORMAT SERDE
OrcSerde
TBLPROPERTIES(
'spark.sql.sources.schema.part.0'='{"type":"struct","fields":[{"name":"coulmnnm1","type":string","nullable":true,"metadat":{}}]

df1.printSchema()

root
|-- columnnm1 : string(nullable=true)